# Spring boot Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: java, spring-boot

My project was running fine yesterday, but today it suddently report an error when I run it.

> 2019-06-04 19:09:57.206  INFO 18231 --- [  restartedMain]
>   ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-06-04 19:09:57.207
>   ERROR 18231 --- [  restartedMain]
>   o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
>   no embedded datasource could be configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:   If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or
>   Derby), please put it on the classpath.   If you have database settings
>   to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no
>   profiles are currently active).
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

my configurationfile `application.yml`

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    database: postgresql
  datasource:
    username: postgres
    password: adminadmin
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

I have postgresql in my dependencies.

```
 implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5" // PostgreSQL driver
```

I tried rebuild, invalid and restart, none is working.

Comment: Do you include implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') ?

Comment: of course, the application was running fine yesterday.

Comment: You can only check do you change anything in your Gradle  ?

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: if `application.yml` is at different location, please ensure that path is added to the program arguments(or environment variable) in your IDE(if you use one).

Comment: Try to add again the database, check the connection then reopen the project with the Gradle file. If it offers to delete your existing project while creating a new one (dont worry it won't remove your actual files), hit accept.
This error often happens with Spring Maven projects too, reopening them with the pom.xml file while deleting the old build like this solves this issue.

Comment: Are you using spring cloud dependencies?

Comment: @Kata It works but I have to reset all IDE configurations. What would be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
    database: POSTGRESQL
  datasource:
    username: postgres
    password: adminadmin
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

and make sure that the postgress.jar is in the classpath of your application and that tomcat takes it up properly.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution of the error  connecting  mongo db with SpringBoot  use following code line your main class **

@SpringBootApplication**(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)**